# reference list with the same author, different dates (years) in APA Style, generated automatically by Mendeley?

Tags: reference, mendeley

I have this issue in the reference list auto-generated by Mendeley

- author published multiple works in different years, mendeley lists the work from new to the oldest automatically.
- i want Mendeley to give the ref list starting from oldest to newest

How do i change this?

thanks

I tried to do it manually in the reference list but it goes back to old list when i click mendeley 'Refresh' option.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.